# How to track my site position in SERP based on keyword

Tags: seo, google-analytics, keywords, search-results

In Google Analytics i can see that people have reach my website after search on a specific keyword. How can i check the results page number where my website appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There are lots of tools available for this](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=seo+rank+checker+software). [Free Monitor For Google](http://www.cleverstat.com/en/google-monitor-query.htm) is very basic and doesn't have a lot of the fluff others have so if you like simple it's worth checking out.

Comment: I need to check my website position for this keyword, not all sites with this keyword so this free monitor is not exactly what I was looking for, but still helpful. Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what this software does

Comment: Well 3 years later I am still using the Free Monitor proposed by John and it is great. The only and unavoidable issue, which does not depend from the tools, is that Google changed their algorythm so much that the SERP depends from hundreds of factors and the result that you see in the tool gives you only a rough idea but this does not assure you that you have scored to this place for all users.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) provides this functionality (along with the ability to see how you rank at localized Google domains, in image search, et cetera) with an approximate SERP rank as well as a percentage-based change in rank indicator for the timeframe you specify within the last 30 days.

Log in and go to "Your site on the web" > "Search queries" - the data you're looking for will be under the "Avg. position" and "Change" columns.

**Edit:** Given that you are looking for an exact keyword, I should qualify that recommendation - you may need to switch from "Queries with more than 10 impressions and clicks" to "All queries" (and then search the text on the page) to get the data you're looking for unless Google is automatically hiding data for the keyword (as will happen if you have thousands of keywords with clicks and impressions).

Note that the tables generated with Google Webmaster Tools can be exported in a variety of formats to aid in tracking your optimization efforts.

Comment: The filter seems to only let you filter on one query (key phrase) at a time.  For ongoing monitoring, it's necessary to be able to quickly look at a whole list of key phrases and see how you're going.

Comment: @ClayNichols Please see the last sentence of that answer. Also: [Don't use unauthorized computer programs to check rankings. Google does not recommend the use of products such as WebPosition Gold™ that send automatic or programmatic queries to Google.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769)

Answer (score 2):

[SEOmoz's Rank Tracker](http://www.seomoz.org/rank-tracker) is useful for some basic reporting. You can check up to 5 searches each day on the free account.

Comment: Awesome tool, limited to the first 50 results but still awesome, thanks.

Comment: SEOmoz appears to no longer have a free option. They have a 30 day free trial of the $99/m Pro account.)

Comment: @Clay you're right, in fact I contacted them ages ago about some bugs in the free version and they said they were releasing a new pro tool and weren't interested in fixing the free one >:(

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SEscout - SERP tracker](http://users.sescout.com/upgrades/subscriptions?invite=u99ez34).  It provides hourly updates, reporting features, notifications and a lot more.  My favorite SERP tracker thus far.  The free account allows for 10 keywords at no cost.

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Web Rank](http://www.advancedwebranking.com/features.html) looks like a really good alternative. I tried it out before. Not as easy to use what we used before (Web Position Gold) but much cheaper.  It is missing the Page Critic which I really liked in WPG.  There's a [review of AWR on SEObook](http://www.seobook.com/advanced-web-ranking-review).